# Why is Heroin being smuggled in A Colder War?

Tags: charles-stross

In [A Colder War](http://www.infinityplus.co.uk/stories/colderwar.htm) by Charles Stross, it is stated several times that the Gates are being used by the protagonists to smuggle heroin.

- The Colonel has "diverted their payload capacity to another purpose",
- The main character is "the guy with the diplomatic passport and the bulging briefcase full of heroin and end-user certificates."
- There is also the scene where the submarine returns:

> Gorman slowly dials it into a combination lock on the briefcase, lets it fall open and unthreads the chain from his wrist. Floodlights glisten on polythene bags stuffed with white powder, five kilos of high-grade heroin from the hills of Afghanistan; there's another quarter of a ton packed in boxes in the crew compartment.

It seems quite clear and nondebatable that the protaganists, a branch of US military/goverment/super-spy types, are smuggling heroin though the gates, at truly unbelievable risks.
I can't see at all why they would be doing that.
I've now read the novella three times and I think I am missing a lot. Perhaps because I did not live through the cold war.

Comment: I found that puzzling too. They're smuggling the heroin from Afghanistan to *Antarctica*, which can't be the final destination; even if travel through the Gates were perfectly safe, how could this be the best route? What obstacle are they avoiding?

Comment: It has been suggested to me that Antarctica is a waystation, that they then carry it onwards via another world.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a reference to the [Iran-Contra Affair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegations_of_CIA_drug_trafficking#Iran-Contra_affair), where the CIA were accused of facilitating the trafficking in illegal drugs in order to fund the (anti-communist) Contra rebels in Nicaragua.

To **hammer.the.point.home** we later learn that the Colonel in charge of the op is indeed a Colonel North. We're also treated to a diatribe from him about the perils of communism and the rise of liberalism:

> “Relax a bit. Drink your coffee.” The colonel paces back behind his
>   desk, sits down. Roger sips cautiously at the brown sludge in the mug
>   with the Marine Corps crest. “The president told me to organize a
>   team,” says the colonel, so casually that Roger nearly chokes on his
>   coffee, “to handle contingencies. October surprises. Those asshole
>   commies down in Nicaragua. ‘We’re eyeball to eyeball with an Evil
>   Empire, Ozzie, and we can’t afford to blink’ — those were his exact
>   words. The Evil Empire uses dirty tricks. But nowadays we’re better
>   than they are: buncha hicks, like some third-world dictatorship —
>   Upper Volta with shoggoths. My job is to pin them down and cut them
>   up. Don’t give them a chance to whack the shoe on the UN table, demand
>   concessions. If they want to bluff I’ll call ‘em on it. If they want
>   to go toe-to-toe I’ll dance with ‘em.” He’s up and pacing again. “The
>   company used to do that, and do it okay, back in the fifties and
>   sixties. But too many bleeding hearts — it makes me sick. If you guys
>   went back to wet ops today you’d have journalists following you every
>   time you went to the john in case it was newsworthy.